# When calculating a car's suspension caster, after turning the steering wheel 20 degrees, why multiply by 1.5?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, geometry

To calculate caster of one side of a vehicle, the steering wheel is turned 20 degrees to the left, and the camber is obtained; this represents the 'in' value of the front right tire. Then the steering wheel is turned 40 degrees in the opposite direction; this is the 'out' value for the front right tire. The two values are subtracted from each other, and then multiplied by 1.5, to obtain the caster, for that particular side of that car.

If the steering wheel is turned by 15 degrees, instead of 20 degrees, the constant is 2.0 instead of 1.5.

For 10 degrees, the constant is 3.0.

I'm wondering how these constants, 1.5/2.0/3.0 are obtained? I presume it has something to do with the unit circle?

Comment: Is that the method for a particular car? Does the suspension have to be normally loaded? A driver of 60kg, half tank of fuel etc?

Comment: This is the method for all cars irregardless of driver weight. Suspension should always be loaded, and ground is leveled for all 4 tires.